# Showing the map $g:X\rightarrow S^1$ from a one-point compactification is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X=(1,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one point compactification and I want to show that it is homeomorphic to the unit sphere by the function $g(x)=(cos(2\pi/x),sin(2\pi/x))$ if $x\in(1,\infty)$ and $g(x)=(1,0)$ if $x=\infty$. I am able to show that $g$ is a bijection but what is left is that I have to show that this is an open map. However I am a bit lost in using the open sets in $X$. Or is there an easier way to define this homeomorphism? (and unfortunately I am not allowed to map $(1,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ or that would be much more easier)

Another approach I can think of is taking the universal property of quotient, but I still need to show continuity of a function from $X$ to $S^1$ which is the part I stuck at.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use the homeomorphism $(1,\infty)\to (0,1)$ given by $x\mapsto \frac 1 x$? Even if so, you might just use it and then bake the $\frac 1 x$ into your functions afterwards to hide $(0,1)$ from the picture …

Comment: Have you shown already that $g$ is continuous? Have you considered the inverse function of $g$?

Comment: @supinf I haven’t shown that $g$ is cts because I was stuck dealing with the point of infinite. If it is simply a function from $[0,1]$ by trig functions it is obviously continuous but in my case I want to map the one point compactification directly to $S^1$ by the $g$ I defined. I know it is continuous but just don’t know how I should write that.

Comment: @Christoph Since I want to plot my function that the range has transformed from $X$ to $S^1$ so I think that would be easier to define a homeomorphism directly. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open intervals $(a,b)$ with $1<a<b$ together with sets of the kind
$$
\{\infty\} \cup (1,a) \cup (b,\infty)\quad\text{with}\quad 1<a<b
$$
form a basis of the topology of the one-point compactification $(1,\infty)$.

Check that the images of these under $g$ are all the open arcs in $S^1$, hence $g$ is open.

Conversely, the open arcs form a basis of the topology of $S^1$ and their preimages under $g$ are exactly the open sets listed above. Hence $g$ is continuous.

We conclude that $g$ is a homeomorphism.